# How to enable syntax highlighting for CS files in Visual Code on OS X?

Tags: c#, asp.net, macos, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

The title says it all. I've recently followed [this](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/tutorials/your-first-mac-aspnet.html) offical Microsoft tutorial to build an **ASP.NET** web app on my MacBook, everything works fine (I can launch the web app) except for the syntax highlighting for `.cs` files. `.js`, `.html` and everything has syntax highlighted **EXCEPT** for C# files...How would I resolve this?

[Here](http://pastebin.com/7cVUz4yQ) is my `project.json` file for your reference (Apologies for the external link, but the file is too huge and will break your eyes if posted here)

Comment: According to https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/csharp you have to install [this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.csharp)

Comment: That was it! Thanks you!!!

Comment: omg thank you so much! This just solved my other SO question :) thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the comments:
In VS Code

Press `CTRL-P`

Enter `ext install csharp`

Enjoy C# syntax highlighting